# Greatest integer value of $[2.999...]$

Tags: functions

What happens to the greatest integer value in case of such non-terminating decimals ?What is  $[2.999...]$ ? Is it $2$ or $3$ ? Does it have connection with limit ?

Comment: By the brackets you mean floor right?

Comment: It is 3. See Kenny's answer.

Comment: Yes . It is floor function .

Comment: If it's non terminating then the answer is 3.  2.99999.... =3.  I had 2.9999999.... eggs in my omelet.  It's really not a weird trick or a mind game or a fuzzy way to look at things to get the answers we want.  It *IS* 3.  And everything that 3 does 2.999999.... does.  Because they are the *exact* same thing.

Answer (score 7):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
x &=& 2.999\cdots \\
10x &=& 29.99\cdots \\
10x-x &=& 27 \\
9x &=& 27 \\
x &=& 3
\end{array}$$

Therefore, $2.999 \cdots = 3$.

Therefore, $\lfloor 2.999 \cdots \rfloor = \lfloor 3 \rfloor = 3$.

---

What might be confusing to you is that $\lfloor 2.\underbrace{999\cdots9}_n \rfloor = 2$ for any finite $n$. That means that the limit as $n \to \infty$ is indeed $2$, which proves that $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is not continuous at $x=3$.

Answer (score 1):

**Does it have connection to limit?**

Yes, any non-terminating decimal $D$ can be considered as a limit of numbers $D_n$ that are written as $D$'s finite decimal substrings of length $n$. The sequence $\{D_n\}$ is monotonic non-decreasing and bounded from above, so the limit of $D_n$ is guaranteed to exist as $n\to\infty$.

(This answers part of your question re:limits. Use in conjunction with the other answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at this, is to consider the following simple proof:

Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a\geq b$, then:

$$2a=a+a\geq a+b\geq b+b=2b$$

Dividing by 2 yields:

$$a\geq\frac {a+b}{2}\geq b$$

That is, there is always a real number in between any two arbitrarily selected real numbers. We say the real numbers are "complete".

So indeed $2.\overline {999}=3$

So, as stated above, $\lfloor 2.\overline {999}\rfloor=\lfloor 3\rfloor=3$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its value derives from the limit of the sum of geometric progression:

$$[2.999...]=[2+0.9+0.09+...]=[2+\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac{0.9\cdot \left(1-0.1^n\right)}{1-0.1}]=[2+\frac{0.9}{1-0.1}]=[3]=3.$$